# Create a regex to convert this type of substring ":30:00" to this other "00:30", only if it matches the established regex pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, python-re

```py
input_text = "a :01:00 pm :30:00 am ; :11:00 am, :00:00 am,: 15:00 pm  : :00:00 am hay 1"
```

maybe it's useful to use re.sub() in conjunction with some pattern that conditions in which cases to correct the original string with a replacement

```py
#input_text = re.compile(r"(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?").sub( , input_text)
```

One of the problems that this can have is not knowing the number of replacements that the program must perform, since the unknown input string is assumed (it may even not be necessary to perform any replacement in case no match is detected)

the output that I need,where you can see that every time I detect the pattern **":XX:00 am"** where the X can be any numeric character, I replace it with **"00:XX am"** inside the original substring:

```py
input_text = "a 00:01 am 00:30 am ; 00:11 am, 00:00 am,: 15:00 pm  : 00:00 am hay 1"
```

Note that if and only if it happens, that `":01:00 pm"` then the substring `"pm"` change by `"am"`, when placing that they are the zero hour of the morning, remaining in the output string this `"01:00 am"`, however in the case of the substring `"15:00 pm"` since it does not match the regex pattern, the substring `"pm"` was not changed by `"am"`, remaining simply as `"15:00 pm"`

How to fix this regex?

Comment: It's not clear from your description as to when `pm` gets converted to `am` nor actually what is a valid match that needs to be converted because you have provided no English-language description. You have instead provided a non-working, incomplete regular expression and I would not want to use this as some sort of specification.

Comment: @Booboo Only **":01:00 am"**, or similar cases, should be converted to **"00:01 am"**.  That is why I have left the examples in the desired output, which contains several cases of those, for example **":15:00 am"** become in **"00:15 am"** ... I need that... and I was trying with regex patterns for the detections in the input string.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because you've not given a very clear specification of the transformation you want to do. Clearly it involves a pattern something like `:XX:YY`, but is the `am` or `pm` afterwards required? Do the `YY` digits always need to be zero? In your example output, the first time changes from `pm` to `am`, which is probably a typo, but that further adds to our confusion. It would help if you could give several input-output pairs with an explanation of why they matched or didn't, and which parts of the input turned into which parts of the output.

Comment: @Blckknght  mmm...  forget about "pm" or "am" that was just to give context to the functionality, but for practical purposes the only thing I need is a regex that if it finds this pattern ":45:00 am" it can be 0, 4 or 5 any other number, so as output it should return the original string but with ":45:00 am" replaced by "00:45 am". And in the case "00:45 am" should not replace anything because it is not preceded by a ":"

Comment: Does `':12:34'` turn into `'34:12'` or do the last two digits in the pattern need to be zero? You keep giving more and more zero examples, which aren't really helpful.

Comment: @Blckknght exactly, but only when it is ":XX:00 am" and remains "00:XX am", the condition is that the 2 numbers after the second ":" are both "0". I add more info in the question. the process is to detect with regex all the occurrences of the pattern ":XX:00 am" in the input string, then correct them all to the form "00:XX am", and finally replace the already corrected substrings in the original string respecting their original positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the pattern `:XX:00` and not at all about anything else around it (like the `am` and `pm` in your examples), this is very easy. You just need the regex pattern `:(\d\d):00` and then you substitute in `00:\1`, where the `\1` stands for the parenthesized group in the matching pattern.

Try this:

```
output_text = re.sub(r':(\d\d):00', r'00:\1', input_text)
```